# How to use application name in URL after port (like we do in tomcat deployed application) for calling rest web service in GWT application?

Tags: java, rest, gwt

I have a GWT application deployed and which i am running via calling a run configuration (Run -> Run Configurations -> Web Application -> create a new configuration -> Run). Now, this process typically deploys project on following URL: **http://127.0.0.1:49240/GWTSample.jsp**

But now, I have integrated rest web service in my project, and which has one URI for rest call as following: **/GWTSample/rest/hello**.

But when I modify actual URL to this: **http://127.0.0.1:49240/GWTSample/rest/hello** this URL does not work.

As a long solution, I have to compile my project and deploy it on Tomcat as following URL: **http://localhost:8080/GWTSample/rest/hello**, which takes more than 10 minutes every time.
So how can i make rest calls on my project on **http://127.0.0.1:49240/GWTSample.jsp** ?

Comment: When GWTSample.jsp is your GWT hostpage why do you want the same URL for your REST service? How is your REST service implemented? As a servlet?

Comment: @vanje Yes, I have added Jersey jars in library, configured web.xml for identifying /rest/* and added servlet mapping in it and created .java file with @path("/hello")

Answer (score 1):

If your hostpage and your REST servlet are in the same web application then the URLs are constant relative to the web application context.

Apparently, your development mode server uses root context `"/"`. So your development URL paths are `"/GWTSample.jsp"` and `"/rest/hello"`. But your external Tomcat uses `"GWTSample"` as context which leads to URL paths of `"/GWTSample/GWTSample.jsp"` for the hostpage and `"/GWTSample/rest/hello"` for your REST service.

To call your REST service from your GWT app you can either use relative URLs or you determine the context path at runtime on server side (see [ServletContext.getContextPath()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath--)) and pass this path to your GWT application (e.g. by integrating it into the hostpage).

The context itself is a deployment detail. Of course, you can configure your Tomcat to use root context, too. But it would be better for your application to not rely on that.